# 404 error when running tomcat on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I'm unable to launch my app after restarting server. Here is the console log

```
Mar 3, 2015 9:11:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.6.0_51\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.6.0_51/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.6.0_51/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.6.0_51/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\git-cheetah\..\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ThinPrint\;C:\Users\ma51574\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\dev\eclipse\eclipse3.7.2;;.
Mar 3, 2015 9:11:24 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:AssessmentUnit' did not find a matching property.
Mar 3, 2015 9:11:24 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:assessment' did not find a matching property.
Mar 3, 2015 9:11:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 3, 2015 9:11:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 3, 2015 9:11:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 467 ms
Mar 3, 2015 9:11:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 3, 2015 9:11:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
Mar 3, 2015 9:11:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\dev\workspaces\fbb\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\AssessmentUnit does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4906)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5086)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Mar 3, 2015 9:11:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Mar 3, 2015 9:11:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Mar 3, 2015 9:11:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/AssessmentUnit] startup failed due to previous errors
Mar 3, 2015 9:11:24 AM org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources cleanUp
WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AssessmentUnit]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.cleanUp(NamingResources.java:988)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.stopInternal(NamingResources.java:970)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5495)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Mar 3, 2015 9:11:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 3, 2015 9:11:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 3, 2015 9:11:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 346 ms
```

Im fairly new to eclipse and not really a backend/java guy.

so any ideas what the issue can be?

any help is appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1- Stop the server

2- Clean the project(Project --> Clean) , the tomcat server (Server--> Right Click --> Clean) and Tomcat work directory (Server--> Right Click--> Clean Tomcat Work Directory).

3- Start the server and run.